# Dash (or minus or subtraction) followed by letter (or function name) causing syntax error in Perl

Tags: perl, syntax, syntax-error

I was surprised when

```
sub f{1};

my $answer = 1-f(1);
```

gave me a syntax error in Perl when I was expecting it to perform subtraction.  Adding a space made it work okay again:

```
sub f{1};

my $answer = 1- f(1);
```

Why does this cause a syntax error in Perl? Is there an ambiguity? Is the dash interpreted as part of the function name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`-f`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) tests whether a file is a plain file, so it does not make sense to perl as it does not see `-` sign. That is why this works as you expect, as there is no `-fo` test.

```
sub fo{1} my $answer = 1-fo(1);
```

(nor there is `+f` test)

```
sub f{1} my $answer = 1+f(1);
```

Comment: Another use case for the `&` sigil!

Comment: More likely, a argument against single-letter subroutine names :-)

Comment: @mob, no, this is a job for the space bar.